# Format SQL Query Result into web menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I am trying to bhuild a drill down menu for my website, where user will click on a category and it will show the subcategories of that clicked category, there could be n-levels. 
I am able to write sql query which returns the output exactaly as I want, but the problem is...I dont want to show the whole menu to end user, I would like to open/expand only clicked category.

```
    my Query output is:

1 IPTV
2      Jadoo Tv
3      Shava Tv
4      Jalva Tv
5 Programming
6      Microsoft
7           Asp.Net
8      PHP
```

so by default IPTV & Programming Should be displayed, since they are parent, and when I click on IPTV it should open the children of IPTV, like I said there could be n-levels.

I was thinking, I can load the output of query to webpage and then control the menu navigation with css/javascript.

do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your code, if you have any?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to write the code. So far i think i will just load the menu to webpage and with CSS set display to "none" for all sub categories, then for every category i will pass category tree as a GET parameter. for example for Asp.net i will pass 2,3,4 (2=Programming,3=Microsoft,4=Asp.net) and then with code i will set only these sub categories to Show and rest Hide. what dou you think about this approach?

Comment: Yes probably a good approach. Make the SQL query return an array of menu items, then loop out the items and add a class or id to each one, then use CSS or a combination of CSS and JS to control the view.

Comment: i am returning the Rows as you see above in my code example with correct number of spaces padded to the left. then just showing them on webpage (since CTE query did the sorting and formating).

Comment: Well you would need some markup to make use of CSS and/or JS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, here is the complete code for markup (after I get the result from sql sp).

```
    Private Sub CreateLeftMenu()

    Dim dt As DataTable = DAL.ReturnMSSQLData("EXEc CategoryTree")
    Dim str As New StringBuilder

    Dim catname As String = ""
    Dim catid As Integer = 0
    Dim parent As Integer = 0
    Dim sort As String = ""
    Dim keys As Array

    Dim display As String = "none"

    For Each item As DataRow In dt.Rows

        catname = Replace(item("CatName"), " ", "&nbsp;")
        catid = item("id")
        parent = item("parent")
        sort = item("sort")

        If parent = 0 Then
            str.Append("<div class='group_" & parent & "'><a href='/pages/index.aspx?cat=" & sort & "' id='group_" & catid & "'>" & catname & "</a></div>")
        Else

            If Len(Me.GroupID) > 0 Then
                keys = Split(Me.GroupID, "_")

                For Each item1 As String In keys
                    If CInt(item1) = parent Then
                        str.Append("<div class='group_" & parent & "' style='display:block'><a style='text-decoration:none' href='/pages/index.aspx?cat=" & sort & "' id='group_" & catid & "'>" & catname & "</a></div>")
                    Else
                        'str.Append("<div class='group_" & parent & "' style='display:none'><a style='text-decoration:none' href='/pages/index.aspx?cat=" & sort & "' id='group_" & catid & "'>" & catname & "</a></div>")
                    End If
                Next

            End If



        End If

    Next

    LMenu.Text = str.ToString

End Sub
```